# Printing to a dot-matrix printer with raw ascii from CUPS

Tags: printing, terminal, ascii, cups, dot-matrix

Please excuse my newbness - I haven't managed to find a functioning answer to this. Perhaps because I don't understand the syntax, or perhaps because it's not quite working with my printer.

I'm trying to print an ASCII file from a mac to a Panasonic KX-P1150, using cups. In Terminal I type:

lp -o raw filename.txt

And it works. However, I'd like to select a higher pitch (smaller point size), which apparently can be done by telling the printer to ESC-g.

*MICRON PITCH
Sets printing to 15 characters per inch (up to 120 characters per line).*

```
Name:   ESC     g
Dec.:   27      103
Hex.:   1B      67
```

What I would love to do is just embed that ESC-g at the top of my text file, presumably as Hex, but no matter what syntax I use, the printer just prints the command without changing its settings.

I've tried \x1b, '[, and some other things. Perhaps this is really simple and someone can set me straight on the syntax?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Please elaborate on the emulation mode of the printer.  As I recall, Printronix has a native mode, an IBM ProPrinter II mode and an Epson ESC/P mode.  That looks suspiciously like Epson ESC/P.

Comment: Also, I had some trouble with getting the printer (OKI) to finish the job, so I had to send a bunch of NULs to it (0xff) (256? 1024k?), especially if the last thing on the page was an IMB (Intelligent Mail Barcode) bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is (ESC/P) code that you are looking for:

```
printf "\x1b@\x1bM\x1b2\x1bI\x01\x1bQ`" | nc lp1 9100
```

This was tested on a CentOS box with nc (netcat) installed.  Code explanation:

```
\x1b@ - Init Printer
\x1bM - CPI=12 (option \x1bP CPI=10)
\x1bI\x01 - set left margin to column 1
\x1bQ` - set right margin to column 96
```

Assuming that lp1 (lp1.example.net) is a network printer on a JetDirect (or compatible) print queue with port 9100 open (and an entry in the hosts file).  I have not tried printing via port 21 or the 515 queues on a JetDirect without going through cups.

If it is not on the network, you may try piping it directly via parallel (lp0), serial (/dev/ttyS**x** where **x** is the serial device location [1-9]) or usb0

```
printf "\x1b@\x1bM\x1b2\x1bI\x01\x1bQ`" | usb0
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE.

One 'keefaz' from linuxquestions.org made a suggestion that fixes this:

```
echo $'\eg' > code.txt
cat code.txt filename.txt > print.txt
lp -o raw print.txt
```